# problem with query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null) on my device

Tags: android

I'm doing my first android application: a Voice recorder. After Recording a .wav file, I save it in my folder "Voice recorder" in the SD card. 
When I try to find all my registrations on the folder with

```
 Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

the method return all files except those in my Folders (I have another directory with music). I tried to mount/unmount sdcrad too.

1. Who updates the database associated with the media file?
2. When is it updated? I have to do or to set something on device/code?
3. Are there permissions on folder to be set?

On the Android emulator the application works. I have a LG p500 with android 2.2.

thanks (I'm sorry for my English i'm italian) 
gianluca

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issue for images .
 custom gallery using Mediastore query is not showing the recently taken images on lg optimus one p500 while it's working on other devices.